# htaccess denied access to specific url with parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My website is being attack from some kinda external hitbot or something... 
and it is making my server blowup and SLOW...

what I would like to do is block all server hits that contain this parameters... I look all over the web with no luck...

the address this hacker or robot is hit my site with is the following :

http://exemple.com/?want-to-earn-money-from-home=emerge&views=7&content=6547

I would like to block access to site and redirect to somewhere else if the 
parameters ?want-to-earn-money-from-home existe in url

all in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can block all such request using this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?.*-to-earn.*money[^&]*&views=\d+&content=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: how can when i add this to my htaccess it still allows me to enter the url in my url.. and it brings me to my site ?? someting i am doing wrong ??
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?want-to-earn-money-from-home=emerge&views=\d+&content=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfModule>`

Comment: and can i have redirect to say google or like nospam.com or something

Comment: Updated rule should redirect to google. Do you already have a working .htaccess?

Comment: kinda working now !  if i want the want-to-earn-money-from-home=**anything** like the **\d**

Comment: i just notice that the first variable changes between the following **how-to-earn-easy-money-fast** and **want-to-earn-money-from-home** ... do you think they maybe a way to catch this variant ? to